# How to use one layout by two different actions in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a micropost rails app where users can create posts, I created a route and an action to display posts that belong to the signed-in user, happens that the general index layout for posts is exactly the same as the "myposts" layout so instead of duplicating code I would like to use just one layout with different parameters.
This is what I have until now:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts 
get '/myposts', to: 'posts#my_posts', as: 'myposts'
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def my_posts
  @myposts= Post.where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div>
    <h1><%= link_to post.title, post %></h1>
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.meme_url(:thumb)), post, :target => "_blank"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**my_posts.html.erb**

```
<% @myposts.each do |post| %>
  <div>
    <h1><%= link_to post.title, post %></h1>
    <%= link_to image_tag(post.meme_url(:thumb)), post, :target => "_blank"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'render' on 'my_posts' action - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Add before 'end' in my_posts action: 
`render :index`